# Add multiple style elements for an item in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I am trying add ellipsis to a item created by ExtJS. I just want to add to this item, thus I don't want to add extra things .css file.

I found out there is "style" parameter that takes in css styles and tried.

```
style: {
  'overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;'
},
```

but this gives me a compilation error.

I found out

```
style: {"background-color": 'red' },
```

works, but I can't figure out how to add a second css style to the same element.

What is the correct way to add more style to the same item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use:

```
style: 'overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;'

// or 

style: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    'text-overflow': 'ellipsis'
}
```